A simple geometry problem for highschoolers
I have a book preparing high school students for math Olympiad (Daniar Ch. Musztari). I am able to solve most of the problems, but there is one that i find difficult. Here it is:
You are given triangle $\text{ABC}$. Two lines, symmetrical to line $\text{AC}$ by lines $\text{AB}$ and $\text{BC}$, intersect at point $\text{K}$. Prove that center of circle described on $\text{ABC}$ (point $O$) lies on line $\text{BK}$.
The book provides two hints for this problem, here are they:

Construct a triangle $\text{EFK}$ in which point $O$ is center of inscribed circle.
Draw a line $\text{L}$ parallel to $\text{AC}$ passing through point $\text{B}$. Let $E$ and $\text{F}$ be points of intersection of $\text{L}$ and lines symmetrical to $\text{AB}$ and $\text{BC}$. Prove that $\text{BK}$ is bisector of angle $\text{EKF}$.

In my opinion there is something wrong with this problem, because at the start if we choose a triangle such that angle $\text{ABC}$ is $90^\circ$, then lines symmetrical will be parallel and wont intersect. I tried assuming $ABC<90^\circ$ and $ABC>90^\circ$, but in both cases couldn't come up with the proof. In case $ABC>90^\circ$ triangle $EFK$ lies outside $ABC$, so the strategy suggested by hints won't work.
Can someone solve the problem or disprove the thesis?
EDIT: Here is a picture of the problem for both cases (sorry for it being a photo) (in second case angle KAC just happens to be right, also sorry for that):

1:

Try learning MathJax and edit your post. Moreover, add an image showing your attempt.

Well, my english is not the best. It means that angle of this line and AB has to be the same as angle BAC. Analogically, the second one has angle with BC line equal to BCA angle

Hello. Welcome to MSE. I do not even understand the problem and your last answer is not enough. Could you, as @M.Riyan already asked, add an image, please ?

Ok, i did that. Sorry for it being a photo, but currently im on my mobile so i cant generate  nice picture. Hope it helps you understand

Are you familiar with the "incenter" and the "excenters" of a triangle?

I am, but not in english language :)

@KarolMatyka Have you tried "google translate" or "DeepL" sites for translation? They are usually good, I believe.

Yes, I know about them. However in my language there isn't shorter form for "center of inscribed circle", so i translated it literally.

First, Your remarks are relevant. Secondly, except the case where $\widehat{ABC}=90°$(but in new geometry of triangle, two parallels intersect in infinity, we work in projective plane), what is claimed is $$\text{TRUE}\label{a}\tag1$$, except for "(in)circle", as @Euclid suggests.

Let $A'$ the midpoint of $[BC]$ and circularly.
Note that $ABE$ and $BFC$ are isosceles.
Hints : draw the incircle of EFK and the ex-circles; in case where $\widehat{ABC}>90°$, prove that $(EC')$ is the external bissector of $\widehat{FEK}$.
You'll have to use theorem : two external bissectors and a bissector intersect in one only point. And angle bissector theorem.
Hope it will help you.


https://www.geogebra.org/classic/zp3ardry

$\eqref{a}.-$ I used a CAS(sagemath) to prove it but methods are far away from highschoolers 'level.

If you found the proof, you could propose it as a solution.

Thank you, now i understand how easy this problem was :) You helped a lot

Are you sure it is so simple ? Take time and make the proof, and then propose it, if you please. You may prove and use that $\frac{EK}{FK}=\frac{EB}{BF}$

What do you mean by propose it?

You could propose your proof as an ANSWER. I only gave hints.
